# Control which worker node gets the driver program in deploy mode cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, cloudera-cdh

I am running multiple `spark-submit applications` using --deploy-mode cluster. However, it seems that only one node in the cluster is getting the driver program for each application. As a result, this node's memory get filled pretty fast.

Is there a way to specify which node in the cluster is assigned the driver program for each application launched using `spark-submit`.

Comment: Were you able to figure out how to do this?